# What is fast download media and how to remove it?

Tags: windows-10

For the past couple of weeks something was installed on my pc. Either a virus or a bloatware that came alongside another software and I did not notice it. It shows custom system tray notifications (not the default windows 10 ones) about software needing update. If I click Update Now Windows will prompt me if I trust the Fast Download Media software.

Where did this software come from? I am unable to find it in the apps settings to uninstall it. How do I remove it?

Comment: It's malware remove it like any other malware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to consider *consulting* `taskmgr`, `appwiz.cpl`, and [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to <s>fight</s> locate and terminate such viri**i**.